# How to copy lines from a csv file that contain "D,1", "D,2", or "D,3" into a txt file where the solutions are in the same order as the csv file

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I copy lines from a .csv file that contain "D,1", "D,2", or "D,3" into a .txt file where the solutions are in the same order as the .csv file? Would I consider using grep? I'm new to the Linux command line and have only used sed and head so far.

Comment: `grep` is a very good choice for this.  In particular, using `grep` with a regexp (regular expression - often the `-e` option) grep will allow you to match the multiple entries.  In the simplest case, doing `grep -e 'D,1|D,2|D,3'` will match those patterns anywhere on a line (the vertical bars separate the various search clauses).  If you want to impress your friends, you could shorten that regexp to just `'D,[1-3]'`.  Deciphering that is an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: so save it to a file, use the shell file-redirection operator, ie. `grep 'something' > myFile`. Good luck.